# Enumerations with Binary keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, enum

I created a simple module, that is used to work as Enumeration. It can store all values with binary keys, so you can find them using binary pattern. It's called grouping.

Groups have the same structure as all values in enum, but their ids(binary keys) are composed from keys of values, that they contains.

Example of enum:

```
A = 0b001
B = 0b010
C = 0b100
```

So group with A and C will have key **0b101**.

### Enum class

```
"use strict";

// References to other modules
// Object type checker module
const object_type = require('./object_type');

function validate_enum (value, type) {
    if (value.type !== type)
        throw new Error('Enum pair is expected to be part of Enum');

    if (   object_type.get(value.id) === object_type.number
        || object_type.get(value.name) === object_type.string)
        return;

    throw new Error(
        'Enum pair is expected to contain' +
        ' id(int), name(string), type(object) and value(any type)'
    );
};


// Static module variable for counting number of enums
let last_enum_identity = 0;

/**
 * Enum class
 * Creating new enumeration:
 *   Usage: new Enum (object, [name])
 *     object - enumeration values initializer
 *     [optional] name - represents name of Enum
 *
 *   Each object in enumeration can hold a value, that can be used with it
 *   Example: Operators.plus.value = (a, b) => a + b
 *
 *   Using array initializer:
 *     Characteristic = new Enum([
 *       'Cool',
 *       'Nice',
 *       'Bad',
 *       'Poor'
 *     ]);
 *
 *   Using object initializer:
 *     Characteristic = new Enum({
 *       'Cool': true,
 *       'Nice': 777,
 *       'Bad': () => 'evil',
 *       'Poor': [6,6,6]
 *     });
 *
 * Adding new values:
 *   Using add_value method:
 *     Usage: this.add_value(key, [value, [id]])
 *       key - value's name as string
 *       [optional] value - value, assigned to object
 *       [optional] id - binary key, used for accessory checking
 *
 *  
 *   Using add_value_object method:
 *     Usage: this.add_value_object(object)
 *       object.name - value's name as string
 *       [optional] object.value - value, assigned to object
 *       [optional] object.id - binary key, used for accessory checking
 *
 *     Can be used to add groups
 *
 * Getting values
 *   Native get:
 *     Usage: this[key]
 *       key - name(string) or index(number) of an object
 *
 *   get function:
 *     Returns value, that matches given key
 *
 *     Usage: this.get(key)
 *       key - name(string) or index(number) of an object
 *
 *     Raises an error on key type missmatch
 *     Returns `null` if key does not exists
 *
 *   get_all function:
 *     Returns list(array) of values, that matches given key
 *
 *     Usage: this.get_all(key)
 *       key -
 *         number - returns objects, on ids matches pattern(key)
 *         string(names) - returns objects, that are specified in key(separated by '|')
 *         array(numbers/strings) - returns objects, by their names or indexes
 *         object(Enum) - returns objects, that given group contains
 *
 * Working with groups
 *   Groups are used to combine enumeration values
 *
 *   Adding new group:
 *     To create group module have built-in function, called group
 *     Group can only be created using elements from the same enum
 *
 *     Usage: module.group(name, enums, [value])
 *       name - Group key(name)
 *       enums - List of values, that group contains
 *       [optional] value - value, that is assigned to object
 *
 *     To add created group to enumerations call add_value_object function
 *     Example: this.add_value_object(module.group(
 *                'Vowels', [this.A, this.E, this.O, this.I, this.U]
 *              ));
 *
 * Working with Enum
 *   Enumeartion have next fields:
 *     id - identifier of enumeration, incrementing on creation
 *     name - enumeration name
 *     enums - list(array) of all values
 *     keys - list(array) of all keys(strings)
 *     values - list(array) of all values, related to enumeration keys
 *     count - count of values
 *
 *   To disable enums's future editing .apply() function is used
 *
 * Working with Enum values
 *   Each value in enumeration have next structure
 *     id - binary key, used for equality and accessory checking
 *     name - string name(key) of value
 *     value - value, assigned to object
 *     type - reference to Enum, that holds this object
 *
 *   Methods:
 *     equals(ogject) - returns true if this object is equal to given object
 *     is(object) - returns true if this object is part of or equal to given object
 *     in(object) - returns true if this object is part of given object
 *     contains(object) - returns true if given object is part of this object
**/
module.exports = function (object, name) {
    // Identifier of current entity
    // Used to compare enums and their values
    this.id = ++last_enum_identity;
    this.name = name;
    if (object_type.get(this.name) !== object_type.string)
        this.name = 'Anonymous';

    // List of all values in Enumeration as an array
    this.enums = [];
    this.keys = [];
    this.values = [];

    // Count of values in Enumeration
    this.count = 0;


    let last_enum_key_identity = 1;
    let last_enum_key_index = 0;

    this.add_value = function (key, value, id) {
        this.add_value_object({
            'id'   : id,
            'type' : this,

            'name' : key,
            'value': value
        });
    };

    this.add_value_object = function(value) {
        if (object_type.get(value) !== object_type.object) {
            throw new Error(
                'Expected value of type object,' +
                `but ${object_type.get(value)} was given`
            );
        }

        if (value.type === undefined) value.type = this;
        if (value.value === undefined) value.value = null;
        if (value.id === undefined) {
            value.id = last_enum_key_identity;
            last_enum_key_identity *= 2;
        }

        value.index = last_enum_key_index++;
        validate_enum(value, this);

        if (this[value.name] !== undefined)
            throw new Error('Value with given name already exists');


        value.equals = function (value) { return this === value; }
        value.is = function (value) {
            if (object_type.get(value) !== object_type.object) return false;
            return this.type === value.type && (this.id & value.id) === this.id;
        }
        value.in = function (value) {
            if (object_type.get(value) !== object_type.object) return false;
            return this.id != value.id && this.is(value);
        }
        value.contains = function (value) {
            if (object_type.get(value) !== object_type.object) return false;
            return this.type === value.type && (this.id & value.id) === value.id;
        }


        this.enums.push(value);
        this[value.index] = value;
        this[value.name] = value;


        this.keys.push(value.name);
        this.values.push(value.value);

        this.count++;
    };


    const itype = object_type.get(object);
    if (itype === object_type.array)
        object.forEach((value, index) => this.add_value(value, index + 1));
    else if (itype === object_type.object)
        Object.keys(object).forEach(key => this.add_value(key, object[key]));


    this.get = function (key) {
        switch (object_type.get(key)) {
            case object_type.number: return this.enums[key] || null;
            case object_type.string: return this.enums[key] || null;

            default: throw new Error(
                'Object of type \'number\' or \'string\' expected,' +
                ` but '${key}'` +
                ` with type '${object_type.get(key)}'` +
                ' was given'
            );
        }
    };

    this.get_all = function (key) {
        switch (object_type.get(key)) {
            case object_type.number:
                return this.enums.filter(value => value.is({
                    'name': 'select_group',
                    'type': this,

                    'id': key
                }));

            case object_type.string:
                return key.replace(/\s+/, '').split('|').map(k => this.get(k));

            case object_type.array:
                return key.map(k => this[k]);

            case object_type.object:
                validate_enum (key, this);
                return this.get_all(key.id);

            default:
                throw new Error(
                    'Key of type \'int\', \'string\' or \'array\' expected,' +
                    ` but ${object_type.get(key)} was given`
                );
        }
    }

    // Freeze Enum, to prevent editing,
    // Wich may cause values relation issues
    this.apply = function() {
        Object.freeze(this.enums);
        Object.freeze(this.keys);
        Object.freeze(this.values);
        Object.freeze(this);
    };

    // Add value, that represents any object in enumeration
    // It uses binary key(id) with all 1s
    this.add_value('ANY', '*', 1073741823); // 2^30 - 1
};

module.exports.group = function (name, enums, value) {
    if (object_type.get(enums) !== object_type.array) {
        throw new Error(
            'Enums should be an array,' +
            ` but ${object_type.get(enums)} was given`
        );
    }

    if (enums.length < 2) {
        throw new Error(
            'Group should contain atleast 2 enumeration values'
        );
    }

    const group = {
        'id': 0,
        'type': enums[0].type,

        'name': name,
        'value': value
    };

    for (let index = 0; index < enums.length; ++index) {
        const enumeration = enums[index];
        validate_enum(enumeration, group.type);
        group.id |= enumeration.id;
    }

    return group;
};
```

### Object type checker module

```
"use strict";

// Uses object prototype name, to get type
const get_type = obj => Object.prototype.toString.call(obj);

module.exports.get = get_type;

// List of all standart types, that are supported by module
module.exports.types = {
    'undefined': get_type(undefined),
    'null'     : get_type(null),

    'boolean'  : get_type(false),
    'number'   : get_type(0),
    'string'   : get_type(''),

    'array'    : get_type([]),
    'function' : get_type(function() {}),
    'object'   : get_type({})
};

// Add shortctcuts for types
module.exports = Object.assign(module.exports, module.exports.types);
```

I want to ask you if my code styles are good or if I need to rework them. I'm also interested in your opinions about the enum's structure.

- Is it good that I have object as value of enums, and didn't create special class for that
- Should I make contains function available only for groups? Or mark type of object(group/value)?

For me it is easier to use `contains` method for every object, but I'm not sure about common practice in using such methods.